# How to solve this problem about

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to solve this problem but unfortunately I couldn't regardless of my attempts. Please help. Thanks.

$a^2 + ab = 4c - a$

$bc + ab = b^2 + 2ac - 5$

$c^2 + ac = ab + bc + 6c$

$a < b < c $

$ a > 0$

$ a = ?, b = ?, c = ?$

Comment: As is, the equation has no integer solutions and one messy real solution $(a,b,c)=(4.03872,28.8737,34.2406)$. If you change the second equation to $bc+ab=b^2+2ac-25$, then the equations have the unique real solution $(a,b,c)=(4,15,20)$.

Comment: To start, you should solve for $a$ in terms of $b,c$.  Then use substitution to solve $b$, then $c$.  Wouldn't be pretty.